# SQL - query optimization

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Suppose you have the following tables:

```
TABLE Car
car_id
num

TABLE Car_description
dsc_id
car_id
model

TABLE Result
res_id
car_id
race_num
result
```

the task is to select max, average scores for races where we have more then 2 cars and Car.num, Car_description.model for best cars. One way to solve it is to write the following query.

```
select r.race_num,
       MAX(score) as MaxScore,
       AVG(score) as AvgScore,
       MAX(case when seqnum = 1 then c.carnum end) as TopCarNum,
       MAX(case when seqnum = 1 then cd.model end) as TopCarModel
from (select r.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by race_num order by score desc) as seqnum
      from Result r
     ) r left outer join
     Car c
     on c.car_id = r.car_id left outer join
     Car_Description cd
     on c.car_id = d.car_id
group by r.race_num
having COUNT(*) > 2
```

But here we perform a sorting of result table in inner query, rather than selecting maximal element, i think it will be time consuming. Is it so? How can we optimize this? Thanks.

Comment: "i think it will be time consuming"  Then test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can help in the performance but try

```
SELECT r.race_num,
   MAX(score) as MaxScore,
   AVG(score) as AvgScore,
   MAX(case when mr.max_score IS NOT NULL then c.carnum end) as TopCarNum,
   MAX(case when mr.max_score IS NOT NULL then cd.model end) as TopCarModel
FROM Result LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT r.race_num, MAX(score) max_score FROM Result r GROUP BY r.race_num) mr 
    ON Result.res_num = mr.res_num AND Result.score = mr.max_score
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Car c
 ON c.car_id = Result.car_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Car_Description cd
 ON c.car_id = d.car_id
 GROUP BY r.race_num
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: it's ok, you only forget group by in the inner select. Thanks.